# Installed laravel-valet with dnsmasq, now host file isn't working anymore

Tags: php, laravel, dnsmasq, laravel-valet

I've installed dnsmasq, cause I wanted to try out laravel-valet for ubuntu.

But it broke my host file. When I try to access localhost or any of my configured host file domains it says: "502 Bad Gateway"

I've tried to remove dnsmasq with: `sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq` and `sudo apt-get purge dnsmasq`, but still my host file isn't working.

Is there known fix for this?

Comment: Eh..valet should install dnsmasq by deafult; maybe your package was old. just uninstall valet completely, then re-install it